# How to move code from render function to a more general reactive function in r shiny?

Tags: r, shiny, shiny-reactivity

In the below demo code (used in one of my earlier questions), I'm trying to move the processing code inside `output[["choices2"]] <- renderTable({...})` function from `renderTable()` and into a separate `reactive()` function. You can see my attempt commented-out, but I got *Error in get_quosure(x, env, quoted) : object 'dat' not found* when I tried running this.

What am I doing wrong?

Btw, I'm trying to do this so I can use `dat` in other places. Maybe there's another way to extract `dat` for use elsewhere without taking it out of `output[["choices2"]] <- renderTable({...})`?

Demo code:

```
library(shiny)

data <- 
  data.frame(
    ID = c(1,1,1,2,2,2),
    Period = c(1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3),
    Values = c(5, 10, 15, 0, 2, 4)
  )

ui <- fluidPage(
  
  h5(strong("Base data frame:")), 
  tableOutput("data"),
  radioButtons(inputId = "showData",
               label = h5(strong("Show from original dataframe:")),
               choiceNames = c('All','First 2 rows'),
               choiceValues = c('All','Rows'),
               selected = 'All',
               inline = TRUE
              ),
  h5(strong("Reactive results:")), 
  tableOutput("choices1"),
  h5(strong("Mirror results x 2:")), 
  tableOutput("choices2")
  )

server <- function(input, output, session) {
 
  output$data <- renderTable(data)
  
  rv <- reactiveValues(choices1=c()) 
  observeEvent(input$showData,{if(input$showData=='Rows'){rv$choices1 <- data[1:2,]} else {rv$choices1<-data}})
  
  output[["choices1"]] <- renderTable({rv$choices1})

  # dat <- reactive(
  #   dat <- rv$choices1,
  #   dat[, 3] <- 2 * dat[, 3],
  #   dat
  # )
  
  output[["choices2"]] <- renderTable({
    # dat()
    # Comment-out the next 3 lines and un-comment the commented to try running my creation of reactive "dat"
    dat <- rv$choices1
    dat[, 3] <- 2 * dat[, 3]
    dat
  })
  
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason why your code wasn't working is due to 2 things:

- You need to put {} after `reactive` --> `reactive({ code })`
- You cannot use commas to separate your lines of code.

BEFORE:

```
dat <- reactive(
    dat <- rv$choices1,
    dat[, 3] <- 2 * dat[, 3],
    dat
)
```

AFTER:

```
dat <- reactive({
    dat <- rv$choices1
    dat[, 3] <- 2 * dat[, 3]
    dat
  })
```

Having changed those 2 things, your code works perfectly and `dat()` can be used in other places apart from `renderTable`.

Btw, just a note, it is the first time that I see that someone uses   `output[["choices2"]]`, I would write `output$choices2`. However, as I see, it works, so... you could use either.

Complete code:

```
library(shiny)

data <- 
  data.frame(
    ID = c(1,1,1,2,2,2),
    Period = c(1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3),
    Values = c(5, 10, 15, 0, 2, 4)
  )

ui <- fluidPage(
  
  h5(strong("Base data frame:")), 
  tableOutput("data"),
  radioButtons(inputId = "showData",
               label = h5(strong("Show from original dataframe:")),
               choiceNames = c('All','First 2 rows'),
               choiceValues = c('All','Rows'),
               selected = 'All',
               inline = TRUE
  ),
  h5(strong("Reactive results:")), 
  tableOutput("choices1"),
  h5(strong("Mirror results x 2:")), 
  tableOutput("choices2")
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  
  output$data <- renderTable(data)
  
  rv <- reactiveValues(choices1=c()) 
  observeEvent(input$showData,{if(input$showData=='Rows'){rv$choices1 <- data[1:2,]} else {rv$choices1<-data}})
  
  output[["choices1"]] <- renderTable({rv$choices1})
  
  dat <- reactive({
    dat <- rv$choices1
    dat[, 3] <- 2 * dat[, 3]
    dat
  })

  output[["choices2"]] <- renderTable({
     dat()
    # Comment-out the next 3 lines and un-comment the commented to try running my creation of reactive "dat"
    # dat <- rv$choices1
    # dat[, 3] <- 2 * dat[, 3]
    # dat
  })
  
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Comment: Now that's easy enough to remember! I've had trouble getting my head around reactivity in general, nice to see something easy! Thank you

Comment: Since you mentioned it, I thought I would note I use ```output[["choices2"]]``` for modules, so I know that's at least one area where it can be helpful since I'm using a ```paste``` in the brackets. Though for the most part I would also just use ```output$choices2```. Of course it's possible I'm just doing things incorrectly!